# Move SQL Server 2008 database files to a new folder location

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Logical Name

- `my_Data`
- `my_Log`

Path:

- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA`
- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA`

FileName:

- `my.MDF`
- `my_1.LDF`

What would be the sql script to move these files to a new location: `D:\DATA`

Database is live so I would need to close existing connections.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You forgot to mention the name of your database (is it "my"?).

```
ALTER DATABASE my SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

ALTER DATABASE my SET OFFLINE;

ALTER DATABASE my MODIFY FILE 
(
   Name = my_Data,
   Filename = 'D:\DATA\my.MDF'
);

ALTER DATABASE my MODIFY FILE 
(
   Name = my_Log, 
   Filename = 'D:\DATA\my_1.LDF'
);
```

Now here you must manually move the files from their current location to D:\Data\ (and remember to rename them manually if you changed them in the MODIFY FILE command) ... then you can bring the database back online:

```
ALTER DATABASE my SET ONLINE;

ALTER DATABASE my SET MULTI_USER;
```

This assumes that the SQL Server service account has sufficient privileges on the D:\Data\ folder. If not you will receive errors at the SET ONLINE command.

Comment: And if you want to change the logical name of the database files, you can do that with `ALTER DATABASE my MODIFY FILE ( Name = <oldname>, NewName = <newname> );`. You must do this with the database online (so for instance, at the end after the `SET ONLINE` but before the `SET MULTI_USER`); [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx).

Comment: Worked for me, but remember to just have ONLY one connection open at the time (I mean also close the server explorer). Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me on SQL Server 2012, after I fixed the permissions on the target folder. The following article helped me with the permissions: http://www.thetwonerds.com/2011/02/03/how-to-copy-folders-and-keep-ntfs-and-share-permissions/. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You can use Detach/Attach Option in SQL Server Management Studio.

Check this: [Move a Database Using Detach and Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187858.aspx)

Comment: Very simple and very efficient. You just have to close all active connections (which sql server is offering to do automatically) and that's it. Thanks.

Comment: sp_attach_db was deprecated in SQL 2005. "Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. " More in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx

Answer (score 6):

To add the privileges needed to the files add and grant right to the following local user: SQLServerMSSQLUser$COMPUTERNAME$INSTANCENAME, where **COMPUTERNAME** and **INSTANCENAME** has to be replaced with name of computer and MSSQL instance respectively.

Comment: I could not get SQLServerMSSQLUser$COMPUTERNAME$INSTANCENAME to work for me.  I'm using SqlServer 2012.  I could not find out the correct account.  I feel dirty for it but I gave Everyone full control.  ISTM that SQL Server should make this easier - then I'd be more likely to do the right thing. :-(

Comment: It's a bit late, but for anyone else seeing this, try granting permissions to the SQL Service itself using "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER".  It worked for me in my default instance of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete procedure to transfer database and logins from an istance to a new one, scripting logins and relocating datafile and log files on the destination. Everything using metascripts.

http://zaboilab.com/sql-server-toolbox/massive-database-migration-between-sql-server-instances-the-complete-procedure

Sorry for the off-site procedure but scripts are very long. You have to:
- Script logins with original SID and HASHED password
- Create script to backup database using metascripts
- Create script to restore database passing relocate parameters using again metascripts
- Run the generated scripts on source and destination instance.
See details and download scripts following the link above.

Comment: Would you detail the procedure instead of just linking to an answer off-site?

Comment: Some details added above :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Some notes to complement the ALTER DATABASE process:

1) You can obtain a full list of databases with logical names and full    paths of MDF and LDF files:

```
   USE master SELECT name, physical_name FROM sys.master_files
```

2) You can move manually the files with CMD move command:

Move "Source" "Destination"

Example:

```
md "D:\MSSQLData"
Move "C:\test\SYSADMIT-DB.mdf" "D:\MSSQLData\SYSADMIT-DB_Data.mdf"
Move "C:\test\SYSADMIT-DB_log.ldf" "D:\MSSQLData\SYSADMIT-DB_log.ldf"
```

3) You should change the default database path for new databases creation. The default path is obtained from the Windows registry.

You can also change with T-SQL, for example, to set default destination to: D:\MSSQLData

```
USE [master]

GO

EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultData', REG_SZ, N'D:\MSSQLData'

GO

EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultLog', REG_SZ, N'D:\MSSQLData'

GO
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/08/mover-base-de-datos-sql-server-a-otro-disco.html