# Error while copying a detached SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am building an application in C#. As a requirement, I need to move the database from one local drive to another.

After reading through the forums, where it was suggested that, the best way to move the database would be :

- Detach the Database
- Move the Database
- Attach the Database

I was able to successfully detach the database with the following code :

```
userConn = new SqlConnection(userdatabase);
userConn.Open();

addConn = new SqlConnection(addInfo);
addConn.Open();

string UserString = "sp_detach_db @DBName, @skipchecks";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(UserString, userConn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DBName", userConn.Database);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skipchecks", false);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();

cmd = new SqlCommand(UserString, addConn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DBName", addConn.Database);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skipchecks", false);           
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
```

This worked fine. However, I am not able to move the Database file. It throws an exception :

> The process cannot access the file '*.mdf' because it is being used by another process

Any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: Actually, ALTER DATABASE is a better way to move, rather than detach. Brent Ozar has a post mentioning this ...

Comment: "alter database to change the file paths, take it offline, copy the files to their new locations, and bring it back online.  It kept log shipping intact" : http://dbpedias.com/blogs/brent-ozar-plf/when-should-you-put-data-and-logs-on-the-same-drive/

Comment: I will have a look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That aside, you need to put a database into single user mode before detaching it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584938/move-sql-server-2008-database-files-to-a-new-folder-location

Comment: I would still be interested to know why it didn't work. I am no expert. But for a similar question in SO, there was a suggestion that detach/copy/attach is a best way forward.

Comment: Well, that's the trouble with the internet! There are plenty of incorrect suggestions out there! :) The reason is as I commented above: you need to place DB in single user mode and make sure no other connections to it.