# Renaming the database and create the database in old name in shows database already exists error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am renaming my database and create the database with an old name in shows database already exist error.

```
use master 

ALTER DATABASE DATABASE1 
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 

ALTER DATABASE DATABASE1 
MODIFY NAME = [DATABASE1_DELETED] 

ALTER DATABASE DATABASE1_DELETED 
SET MULTI_USER
```

Now the query executed correctly and renamed the database, but again I am trying to create the database with the old name like this:

```
IF DB_ID('DATABASE1') IS NULL 
   CREATE DATABASE [DATABASE1]
```

Now it shows an error:

> Msg 5170, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot create file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.EASYDIRECT\MSSQL\DATA\DATABASE1.mdf' because it
>   already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the
>   operation.
>   Msg 1802, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

How can I create the database with the old name?

Comment: Your `ALTER DATABASE ....` only renames the **logical** database name - but the **physical files** are still present with the old name (`database1.mdf` and `database1.ldf`). So either you need to rename the **physical files** as well, or you need to create the database with different file names

Comment: @marc_s is spot-on that is the problem.

Comment: @marc_s: The linked question gives helpful additional info, but it's certainly not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ALTER DATABASE ....` only renames the **logical** database name - but the **physical files** are still present with the old name (`database1.mdf` and `database1.ldf`). So either you need to rename the **physical files** as well, or you need to create the database with different file names.

So try this:

```
select * from sys.databases where name like 'Database1%'
```

Now rename your database as you've done before - run the command again. Now you should see an entry for `Database1_Deleted`, correct?

Now run this command:

```
select * from sys.database_files where name like 'Database1%'
```

I bet you now see two entries - one for `Database1_Deleted` and another for `Database1_Deleted_log` - but both are still referencing `Database1.mdf` and `Database1.ldf` respectively - correct?

So to solve this, you need to **also** rename the **physical files**:

```
ALTER DATABASE Database1
MODIFY FILE (NAME = Database1_Deleted, 
             FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.EASYDIRECT\MSSQL\DATA\Database1_Deleted.mdf')
GO

ALTER DATABASE Database1
MODIFY FILE (NAME = Database1_Deleted_log, 
             FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.EASYDIRECT\MSSQL\DATA\Database1_Deleted_Log.ldf')
GO
```

You might need to adapt this to your own database name(s) and physical file locations - but you should get the idea - right?

Comment: Yes I got an idea, thanks Marc

Answer (score 2):

Although you have renamed the your old database in SQL, that database physical location on hard disk have not changed. When you try to create new DB without specifying a file names it will use, it will try to be created on default path and with default file names - which is where old database is.

You can solve it in two ways.

Either create new database with different file names:

```
USE master
GO
CREATE DATABASE DATABASE1
ON 
( NAME = DATABASE1_DATA,
   FILENAME = 'c:\Your_Location\Your_Folders\new_database1.mdf' ) --or any name you choose other then database1.mdf
GO
```

Or other option, rename old databases's files. This requires taking Db offline, setting new file paths, manually renaming the files in windows and taking DB back online.

Here is an example of that: [Move SQL Server 2008 database files to a new folder location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584938/move-sql-server-2008-database-files-to-a-new-folder-location)