# SQL Server recovering database after relocating files

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a tool to move a lot of database files to a different partition. These databases are using SIMPLE recovery and don't get changed much, so I thought something like this would do:

```
// this is a mix of sql commands and disk copy commands

// single user, then offline
SQL: ALTER DATABASE [MY_DATABASE] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
SQL: ALTER DATABASE [MY_DATABASE] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

// copy to target folder
COPY "SOURCE\MY_DATABASE.mdf" "TARGET\MY_DATABASE.mdf"
COPY "SOURCE\MY_DATABASE_LOG.ldf" "TARGET\MY_DATABASE_LOG.mdf"

// delete from source folder
DELETE "SOURCE\MY_DATABASE.mdf"
DELETE "SOURCE\MY_DATABASE_LOG.ldf"

// modify
SQL: ALTER DATABASE [MY_DATABASE] MODIFY FILE (name = 'MY_DATABASE',
    filename = 'TARGET\MY_DATABASE.mdf');
SQL: ALTER DATABASE [MY_DATABASE] MODIFY FILE (name = 'MY_DATABASE_LOG',
    filename = 'TARGET\MY_DATABASE_LOG.ldf');

// multi user, then online
SQL: ALTER DATABASE [MY_DATABASE] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
SQL: ALTER DATABASE [MY_DATABASE] SET ONLINE
```

However, the last operation (`SET ONLINE`) often hangs and waits some time, and when I query `master.sys.databases` I can see that the state is `RECOVERING`.

Can somebody explain why this is happening, what am I doing wrong here, or if I should do the whole thing in a different way?

Comment: You should *detach* the database, not just take it offline. Then *attach* the files in the new server, not alter an existing database and just expect this to work

Comment: Check [Move a database using detach and attach (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-a-database-using-detach-and-attach-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). In the list of methods to move a database, notice there's no option of simply taking the database offline

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: thanks, I'll check this. It's slightly confusing that the MSDN link states *"we recommend that you move databases by using the ALTER DATABASE planned relocation procedure, instead of using detach and attach. For more information, see [Move User Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-user-databases?view=sql-server-ver15)."* When I click the [Move User Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-user-databases?view=sql-server-ver15) link, this procedure doesn't use detach.

Comment: Only if you move the files around for the *same* instance

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: while some answers recommend `DETACH`, I've also found plenty of highly upvoted answers which don't, so I am not sure what's the difference: [1) How do I move SQL Server database files?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/52007), [2) Moving SQL DB files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/254673), [3) Move SQL Server 2008 db](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6585195/69809). Yes, I am moving them to a different NAS inside the same instance, otherwise `ALTER DATABASE` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: In both cases the server has to perform the same housekeeping it performs when it first starts, roll forward any successful transactions that haven't made it to the data pages and roll back any failed transactions. Long delays may be due to frequent log file increases. Check the [RECOVERING](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-different-sql-server-database-states/) section in the linked article